# Autocomplete - How to put all values in one row

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to put all the values and input field for multi autocomplete on one line. But the input field sliding down.

My code:

```
    const { filter, classes, options } = this.props;
    const style = filter && filter.value !== '' ? {backgroundColor: 'lavender'} : {};

    return (
        <TableFilterRow.Cell { ...this.props } className={ classes.cell } style={ style }>
            <Autocomplete
                options={options}
                value={options.filter(option => filter.includes(option.value)) || []}
                getOptionLabel={option => option.label}
                multiple={true}
                fullWidth
                disableClearable={true}
                onChange={this.handleFilter}
                renderOption={option => (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <Checkbox
                            color="primary"
                            checked={filter.includes(option.value) || false}
                        />
                        {option.label}
                    </React.Fragment>
                )}
                renderTags={values => values.map(option => option.label).join(', ')}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                        {...params}
                        fullWidth
                        margin="dense"
                    />
                )}
            />
        </TableFilterRow.Cell>
```

Result:
[image]

How can I put all the values and input field for multi autocomplete on one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use style hook API to select input and apply `flexWrap` and `overflow` CSS properties:

```js
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& > .MuiAutocomplete-root .MuiFormControl-root .MuiInputBase-root": {
      flexWrap: "nowrap",
      overflowX: "scroll"  // or "hidden"
    }
  }
}));
```

then, on component use on `className`:

```js
      ...
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Autocomplete
      ...
```

See this working on codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-zd60g).

Comment: It works! How can I correct the layout for underline and endAdornment?
https://ibb.co/xJkDsY1

Comment: Added `position: "initial"` for solution this problem.